# Plot Logistic Differential Equation Solution from Sympy

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I was computing the logistic differential equation of:

**y' = ky(L-y)**

The computation works. The only thing does not work is I can't plot it with either matplotlib.pyplot or sympy.plot

I think the problem is how to define the `ft` variable of the `f`.

This is the MWE:

```
# https://natelemoine.com/using-sympy-for-biological-odes/

import sympy as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sympy.abc import L, k, t
y = sm.Function('y')(t)

# The differential equation: y' = ky(L-y)
# Define the derivative of y with respect to t (the left-hand side of the ODE),
# and then define the right-hand side of the ODE.
dy = y.diff(t)
rhs = k*y*(L - y)

# Define the equality
eq = sm.Eq(dy, rhs)
print('the Differential equation is:')
sm.pretty_print(eq)

print('the Differential equation solution is:')
sol = sm.dsolve(eq)
sm.pretty_print(sol)

print('the solution of the Differential equation for initial value of y(0) = 800:')

t0 = sol.args[1].subs({'t': 0})
n0 = 800
eq_init = sm.Eq(n0, t0)

C1 = t0.args[2].args[0].args[0]
t0_sol = sm.solve(eq_init, C1)
# substitute the expression for C1 back into the equation
final = sol.args[1].subs(C1, t0_sol[0])
final_eq = final.simplify()
sm.pretty_print(final_eq.subs([(L,2000),(k,0.0003)]))

f = final_eq.subs([(L,2000),(k,0.0003)])
ft = np.linspace(0, 10, 1)

plt.plot(f, ft)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you would like to plot `f` as a function of time. The problem is this:

```py
plt.plot(f, ft)
```

`plt.plot` requires two arguments, a list of x-coordinates and a list of y-coordinates. Clearly, you provided a symbolic expression as the first argument and matplotlib doesn't know what it is.

Solutions. The easiest way to plot a symbolic expression is using sympy's plotting capabilities or the [SymPy Plotting Backends module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
sm.plot(final_eq.subs([(L,2000),(k,0.0003)]), (t, 0, 10))
```

[image]

If you want to use matplotlib directly, you would have to convert your symbolic expression to a numerical function and evaluate it. For example:

```py
f_num = sm.lambdify([k, L, t], final_eq)
t_coords = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y_coords = f_num(0.0003, 2000, t_coords)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t_coords, y_coords)
plt.xlabel("x [s]")
plt.ylabel("f(t)")
```

Comment: Wow thanks again @Davide_sd, I don't know about this `sm.lambdify` that should be used to convert the symbolic expresion to numerical function. It will help me a lot in the future.